# Asking a question whose answer is n-th

Tags: questions, nombres

How do you ask a question whose answer is n-th (the order that is)?

For example, how can I convert the sentence "I was the fourth to get a copy" into a question where the answer is "I was the fourth". There isn't a straightforward way of doing so in English – "Among those who got a copy, are you the first, second or what?" – and I suppose it may also be the case in French.

Comment: I asked the question out of curiosity, considering that in many Asian languages there are actually question words for "what order" or "what n-th".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*[Quantième](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/quanti%C3%A8me)* is in theory the correct term, but it's high literary at best these days. Although it may not be recognized by dictionaries, *[combientième](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/combien)* will be understood by everyone. e.g. ["7 milliards d’humains sur Terre. Et vous, vous êtes le combientième ?"](http://metrofrance.com/blog/bigbugblog/2011/10/28/7-milliards-d-humains-sur-terre-et-vous-vous-etes-le-combientieme/)

> *Le quantième es-tu qui ait eu une copie ?* (literary, might give a native speaker pause, at least in France)
>   *Tu étais le combientième à avoir une copie ?* (common spoken French, less common in writing)

Comment: Wow that's interesting. English definitely doesn't have an equivalent for that.

Comment: "Le quantième es-tu ?" il y a une faute d'accord. Et trop peu de caractères à modifier pour pouvoir modifier.

Comment: @FrenchNoob "Combientième" can be translated to "whatth" in English. It is informal just like its French equivalent, though rarely used, but there are definitely equivalents, more than one too.

Comment: *Quantième* is in common use in all registers in Belgian French. *Combientième* is a transparent derivation, so it should be understood here after at worst an instant of hesitation.